# How does one keep track of when an individual user has viewed an object

Tags: web-deployment, crud

In a CRUD app, I want to store whether or not a user has previously viewed a resource. I'm not very experienced with web development, so I'm not sure what the normal pattern is here.

My naive approach would be to create a table for each user, and store viewed posts there, but that doesn't sound right.

Comment: That's basically what you have to do in some variation or other.

Comment: If this is more of a convenience thing and does not have to be super-durable or accessible from a central location, you could also store this information client-side.

Answer (score 0):

- Use Analytics
- create daily analytics table in that table create fields like

  **id
     *date
     *view_count
     *user_id 
     *user_email

  *once user visit for that day increase visit count so that will avoid data redudancy.
- also it will help you to track daily view analytics